# Symfony2 autogenerated HTML5 constraints does not work

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a form with Symfony2 (v2.3.6) and take advantage of the autogenerated HTML5 constraints.

So, I created a very simple form with just one field with a `RegEx` constraint:

```
public function formAction()
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('animalName', 'text', array(
        'constraints' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex('/(cat|dog)/')
    ))->getForm();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($this->getRequest());
    }

    return $this->render('MeTestBundle:Default:form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

And, in Twig, nothing out of the ordinary.

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Well, as a final result, I was expecting `animalName` field to has a `pattern` attribute with value `(cat|dog)`. As it says in [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#htmlpattern), Symfony would generate the `htmlPattern` of this constraint (I tested it, it returns `.*(cat|dog).*`, which is ok), and this attribute would be used on client side validation by using `pattern` HTML attribute on the `input` element. But there is no `pattern` attribute, the generated code is as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="form_animalName" name="form[animalName]" required="required" />
```

After a little research, I think that the responsible of guess the value of `pattern` attribute is `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorTypeGuesser`, but this service is never initialized (I wrote a `die` in it constructor and also forced the container to get the service to check if `die` is reached).

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have this problem still in Symfony 2.5. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: @Paulpro basically, Symfony developers told me that this behaviour is on purpose and occurs when you manually set the form type, a no-sense from my POV: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3661

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following code:

```
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('animalName', 'text', array(
                'pattern' => '/(cat|dog)/'
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

Rendered HTML I got:

```
<div id="form">
<div><label for="form_animalName" class="required">Animal name</label>
<input type="text" id="form_animalName" name="form[animalName]" required="required" pattern="/(cat|dog)/">
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="kAg4Ww2oH9WQX6fPSyvJd4pNx-xE7B4G0NbIXtUWWDY">
</div>
```

I got the answer from:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3766
Please look into it for more information.

Answer (score 0):

While looking to resolve the issue myself, I came across this question, albeit old, I figured I'd post my findings for any others looking as to why.

Looking at the Symfony source code, the `pattern`, and other HTML5 validations are only added through the [`guessers`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/type_guesser.html) and are only called under `createBuilderForProperty`, used only when the builder property `type` is `NULL` [source code](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/2.8/FormBuilder.php#L105) and the `data_class` is specified. It appears to be persistent from 2.0 to 3.4 - I did not look into 4.x.

To resolve the issue, you would need to exclude the explicit `type` and specify a `data_class` model that holds the desired constraint validations. Then Symfony will use the [`guessers`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/type_guesser.html) to determine the type and attributes to add to the HTML5 elements.

**Form Builder**

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, ['data_class' => AnimalModel::class])
    ->add('animalName')
    ->getForm();
```

**Data Class Model**

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class AnimalModel
{

    /**
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/(cat|dog)/")
     */
    private $animalName;

    public function getAnimalName()
    {
        return $this->animalName;
    }

    public function setAnimalName($name)
    {
        $this->animalName = $name;

        return $this->animalName;
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
<!-- {{ form(form) }} -->
<input type="text" id="form_animalName" name="form[animalName]" pattern=".*((cat|dog)).*">
```